# Notepad++ How to delete Line Numbers?

Tags: notepad++

I need help with Notepad++

Example:

```
Line 19: id_24|5465$
Line 20: id_25|4637$
....
```

how do I delete the line numbers at the beginning of each line?

Need result:

```
id_24|5465$
id_25|4637$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is possible to do it manually you can press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and select the whole block of text and press delete.

You can also do it with a regex. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select regular expression in extended search mode. Search for

```
Line\s(.*):.
```

and replace with nothing.

Comment: can i dot it regex way?

Comment: Yes you can. Do you know a programming language?  -/edit You can actually do it in notepad++. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers I was not aware of this possibility very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement of the accepted answer by Erwin Rooijakkers

Use this regex to remove line numbers generated on obtaining the result of a search in Notepad

```
 \tLine \d*:[ ]*
```

This regex will match a tab followed by `Line` followed by a number, a colon `:` and any trailing blank spaces.

Example input:

```
  Line 77:   05/04/18 10:31:53:780 DEBUG 
  Line 162:  05/04/18 10:31:59:862 DEBUG 
  Line 248:  05/04/18 10:32:05:916 DEBUG 
  Line 357:  05/04/18 10:32:12:007 DEBUG 
  Line 501:  05/04/18 10:32:18:055 DEBUG 
  Line 547:  05/04/18 10:32:24:090 DEBUG 
  Line 1563: 05/04/18 10:34:37:040 DEBUG
```

After using replace applying as paremeters the aforementioned regex [Search] and nothing [Replace with]:

```
05/04/18 10:31:53:780 DEBUG
05/04/18 10:31:59:862 DEBUG
05/04/18 10:32:05:916 DEBUG
05/04/18 10:32:12:007 DEBUG
05/04/18 10:32:18:055 DEBUG
05/04/18 10:32:24:090 DEBUG
05/04/18 10:34:37:040 DEBUG
```

The original regex will remove part of the timestamp and we may need to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the column mode editing: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Comment: thanks for soltuion can i dot it regex way i think its little faster?

Comment: Yes, you can use the find and replace tool (ctrl + h), select "Regular Expression" at the bottom and put "\n^[^:]*: " (without the quotes) in the "find what" textbox and "" (empty) in the replace with textbox. Maybe you'll need to customize the regex but I tested that one and it worked.